# Usage of var keyword in Groovy

Tags: groovy

From Groovy [documentation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_variable_definition): *Variables can be defined using either their type (like `String`) or by using the keyword `def` (or `var`) followed by a variable name, `def` and `var` act as a type placeholder, i.e. a replacement for the type name, when you do not want to give an explicit type:*

```
String x
def y
var z
```

---

But when I try to use the `var`, e.g:

```
var blah = 'ha?'
```

i get the exception:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: statements.var() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [ha?]
Possible solutions: wait(), run(), run(), every(), any(), wait(long)
```

What the Groovy `var` keyword is used for?

Comment: What version of Groovy are you using? `var` is fairly recent in Java, and I suspect Groovy accommodated that (meaning it can only be in recent versions). Seems to work in 3.0.9 though

Comment: Yes, version of Groovy is 2.4.6 (underlying Java is 1.8). `var` is introduced in Java 10, that's the reason then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`var` can be used in Groovy 3+ (Java 8+)